# External monitor display in vertical (portrait) format

Tags: samsung, external-display, auto-rotation, orientation

The Samsung 7's default is output only in horizontal format, as far as I've read. There is a way to wipe the phone, then change the code and restart it. I've tried all the orientation apps, but they only work on the phone, not the monitor. Also looking at Odroid.

Can I cast an Android screen onto a TV Monitor via Windows Wireless Display Adapter, but the image is vertical regardless of the phone's orientation? Perhaps 3rd-party hardware? software? etc.?